# blog archive page styled from default template instead of from custom template

Tags: archive-template

I use latest WP version with the Twenty Twenty-Two theme.

I have created a custom template, named “Blog archive custom page” in order to use it for my blog archive page. I created a new page "Articles" and set it’s template to the “Blog archive custom page” template, through Dashboard > All Pages > Edit "Articles" > Settings sidebar > Page tab > Template.

I added a query loop block inside the “Blog archive custom page” custom template and I set the "Articles" page as Posts page in Settings > Reading.

When I view the "Articles" page, it is styled out from the default “Blog home” template (built-in) and not the custom template (“Blog archive custom page”) I assigned before, as I would expect, although I see that it is assigned as Template in All Pages > Edit "Articles" page > Settings sidebar > Page tab.

Also, when I go to Site Editor > Pages > click on my "Articles" page, on the top of the left sidebar menu, “Blog Home” is displayed instead of “Blog archive custom page”.

Therefore, in order to edit the template of the "Articles" page, I have to edit the default "Blog Home" template instead of the custom “Blog archive custom page” that I created. How could I fix this, so I attach the custom template to my page?

I was wondering if I have missed something.